Variance and expected value of power of normal matrix elements
Here is the next problem: we have $n\times n$ random matrix $\hat{A}$, each element of this matrix is independent real random variable with normal distribution ($\mu=0, \sigma^2=1/n$). Matrix is no-symmetric.
The question is how to find variance and expected value of elements of power from this matrix $(A^m)_{ik}$, where $m$ is natural number? I think diagonal and non-diagonal elements will have different values of variance and expected value, but just now I don't know how to start.

The question needs a little more work by the author.  I recommend reading the guidelines https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask
I encourage to read "Search, and research" and "Make it relevant" sections
